# How to avoid a DialogFragment being dismissed when the Search button is pressed - Android

Tags: android, dialog, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-fragments

After setting:

```
MyDialogFragment fragment = new MyDialogFragment();
fragment .setCancelable(false);
```

it is still dismissed after click on search button.
and i haven't found option like in activity to override onKeyDown();

I need  create dialog that will be shown until my "dismiss" button is pressed.Please Help

Comment: I strongly encourage you to redesign your UI such that this is not needed. http://blog.radioactiveyak.com/2010/08/what-you-can-do-with-your-modal-dialogs.html

Comment: Put the message in whatever fragment that triggered the need for the message. Most Web apps, for example, display error messages inline on the page, not via a modal dialog.

Answer (score 8):

I've just found an answer. After DialogFragment was created we can get the its dialog

```
Dialog dialog = getDialog();

if( null!= dialog)
{
   dialog.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
{

        @Override
    public boolean onKey ( DialogInterface dialog , int keyCode , KeyEvent event )
    {
        // disable search button action
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
}
```

Comment: DialogFragment is NOT a Dialog and it does NOT have setOnKeyListener.

Comment: @Ixx But it contains the dialog so the answer I provided solve the problem. 
Your comment is completely irrelevant.

Comment: FYI, this is the correct answer.  Thanks to Hoochwo for this technique.  Google should have made onCancel return a true/false to see whether it should be cancelled/dismissed instead of just having a method that lets you know the dialogfragment was cancelled via the back button :-P

Answer (score 0):

`getFragmentManager().popBackStack();`

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Hoochwo until button isn't pressed? meaning they need to hold the button down to view the dialog?

Comment: @Hoochwo looks like a bug I would think what you are doing should work. As a temporary fix I would suggest overriding onKeyDown in the container activity to stop the back button from working if you do a findFragmentById and find its an instanceof your dialogframent.